# PHP 5.3.2 alternative to using $this inside an anonymous function?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am using Laravel 4 and PHP to build a new application.  It works fine on my dev server running PHP 5.4.x however my boss insist that it has to run version 5.3.2

I have spent the whole day fixing everything to work with 5.3.2 and almost have everything, so I thought, until I ran into an issue with the code below.

My problems start at this line...
 `DB::transaction(function($clock_in_webcam_image) use ($clock_in_webcam_image)`

I believe this type of code might not work with this version of PHP?  If that is the case, what are my options to run this same code or have it doing the same action?

Would appreciate any help with this.  Very unfortunate that my boss told me straight out that no he will not allow us to update to a newer PHP so I am stuck in a hard spot right now

```
// Create a new time card record when a User Clocks In
public function createTimeCard($clock_in_webcam_image) {
    // Create both Timecard and timecard record tables in a Transaction
    DB::transaction(
        function ($clock_in_webcam_image) use ($clock_in_webcam_image) {
            $timeCard = DB::table('timeclock_timecard')->insertGetId(
                array(
                    'user_id'               => $this->user->user_id,
                    'clock_in_datetime'     => $this->dateTime->format($this->dateFormat),
                    'clock_in_timestamp'    => $this->dateTime->getTimestamp(),
                    'clock_in_webcam_image' => $clock_in_webcam_image
                )
            );

            $timeCardPunchEntry = DB::table('timeclock_punch_entry')
                ->insertGetId(
                    array(
                        'timecard_id'          => $timeCard,
                        'user_id'              => $this->user->user_id,
                        'created_at_datetime'  => $this->dateTime->format($this->dateFormat),
                        'created_at_timestamp' => $this->dateTime->getTimestamp(),
                        'clock_type'           => 'clock_in',
                        'webcam_image'         => $clock_in_webcam_image
                    )
                );

            return $timeCard;
        }
    );
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

In response to bansi's comment...is this what you mean to do...

```
DB::transaction(function() use($myModel){
    $myModel->updateTable1();
    $myModel->updateTable2();
})
```

Comment: hmmm... isn't php 5.3.0 onwards have anonymous functions and namespaces?

Comment: I'm not 100% that is the issue however I can return the value of `$clock_in_webcam_image` right before it goes into the anonymous function and it works, after it is inside it spits a 500 server error and does not work.  When I run this code on my dev server using 5.4.x it works without a problem

Comment: i think i found something. closure has problems with php 5.3.x especially the `$this` is not supported. you can to move your closure to normal private class function and call it.

Comment: @bansi I am not sure exactly which part you mean to move and how to call it, if you have the time could you possible post a demo answer?

Comment: @bansi I updated my question at the bottom, is that what you mean, something like that?

Comment: Doesn't laravel require 5.3.7

Comment: @JoeyD473 It does from several people have gotten it to work on 5.3.2 by replacing the Hashing functions with a new one that is on Github

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before PHP 5.4.0, you could not use `$this` inside an [anonymous function](http://php.net/manual/functions.anonymous.php). There is a simple workaround though where you can use the `use` construct to pass variables into the functions scope. Also, you are using the `use` construct incorrectly as `$clock_in_webcam_image` is not defined in the parent scope.

```
$user = $this->user;
$dateTime = $this->dateTime;

DB::transaction(function($clock_in_webcam_image) use ($user, $dateTime) {
    // snip

    array(
        'user_id' => $user->user_id,
        'clock_in_datetime' => $dateTime->format($this->dateFormat),
        'clock_in_timestamp' => $dateTime->getTimestamp(),
        'clock_in_webcam_image' => $clock_in_webcam_image
    )

    // snip
});
```

Comment: i think this will work +1 for you. i know PHP 5.3 support closures. but the `$this` was removed Ref: [Removal of $this in closures](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/closures/removal-of-this)

Comment: This works!  Thanks Phil and @bansi for your efforts!  If only my boss would let me upgrade to PHP 5.3.2 I feel like i'm being held back years

Comment: Also when you said I am using `$clock_in_webcam_image` incorrectly.  Did you mean it should be like this `DB::transaction(function() use ($clock_in_webcam_image, $user, $dateTime)` or like in your example where it is passed into the function but left out of the `use` part?  Appreciate your help this is all stuff I haven't had to work with until now

Comment: @jasondavis nice to hear it worked. you are lucky. I had to make compatibility for php 4.2.1 couple of months back.

Comment: @bansi yikes sounds like a nightmare!  This wasn't much fun as Laravel is more cutting edge and uses all the latest PHP stuff but now getting this last bit to work, I have pretty much resolved all issues and Laravel is running on 5.3.2 smoothly so far.  I was about to give up and just remove the Transaction functionality altogether.  You and Phil have been a great help, I would select both your answers if it was possible

Comment: @jasondavis You use the `use` construct to pass variables from the parent scope into the closure. `$clock_in_webcam_image` is not defined in the parent scope so you cannot pass it to `use`. I assumed that is passed into the closure via `DB::transaction` as its sole argument.

Answer (score 0):

try this. please check you don't have another `insertTimecard` defined.

```
// Create a new time card record when a User Clocks In
public function createTimeCard($clock_in_webcam_image)
{

    // Create both Timecard and timecard record tables in a Transaction
    DB::transaction($this->insertTimecard($clock_in_webcam_image));
}


private function insertTimecard($clock_in_webcam_image)
{
    $timeCard = DB::table('timeclock_timecard')->insertGetId(
        array(
                'user_id' => $this->user->user_id,
                'clock_in_datetime' => $this->dateTime->format($this->dateFormat),
                'clock_in_timestamp' => $this->dateTime->getTimestamp(),
                'clock_in_webcam_image' => $clock_in_webcam_image
        )
    );

    $timeCardPunchEntry = DB::table('timeclock_punch_entry')->insertGetId(
        array(
                'timecard_id' => $timeCard,
                'user_id' => $this->user->user_id,
                'created_at_datetime' => $this->dateTime->format($this->dateFormat),
                'created_at_timestamp' => $this->dateTime->getTimestamp(),
                'clock_type' => 'clock_in',
                'webcam_image' => $clock_in_webcam_image
        )
    );
    return $timeCard;
}
```

Comment: I see now, looks nice thanks for your help, ill try this out shortly and select you answer if it works out, thanks a bunch

Comment: I small thing, should `DB::transaction(insertTimecard($clock_in_webcam_image));` be `DB::transaction($this->insertTimecard($clock_in_webcam_image));` ?

Comment: yes i missed that it is a typo. thanks for pointing out. fixed it

Comment: Thanks for your help, I am a step closer I think but now I am logging this error message... `exception 'ErrorException' with message 'Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Connection::transaction() must be an instance of Closure, null give`  I don't get it, isn't passing these functions into `DB::transaction()` considered a Closure?

Comment: you are getting into trouble, if Database class is not written by you. it expects closure and php 5.3.x don't support it

Comment: The worse part is it partially works, it makes the first DB entry then fires off a 500 server error which prevents another SQL query from running tat is need to set the user table as a clocked in user...if it would just keep running it would all work!  Maybe tomorrow I can come up with a new plan, thank for you help

Comment: @bansi PHP 5.3 does support closures